# Get a link from many matching links on a page?

Tags: php, html, dom

I am grabbing the HTML of a remote page with `file_get_contents()`, and in this remote page there are loads of links I can grab with a `$dom`.

However the problem I'm having is the link I want contains a specific value '/vue/', and there are anywhere from 1 to 1000 links on the page with the same value in it. The `/vue/` part is the only static element in the links.

I only need one of these links, it doesn't matter which one.
How would I go about grabbing just one link out of the huge number of them?

Here is the code I currently have to grab all the links:

```
     foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {

  if(strpos($node->getAttribute('href'),'/vue/') !== false) {

      $Epsiodes = $node->getAttribute('href')[0];

  }

  }
```

But `$Epsiodes` comes back blank.

Comment: What have you tried in order to get that link? can't you just fetch those links and then do `$iChose = $link[0];`

Comment: I tried using the following     foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {
   
   if(strpos($node->getAttribute('href'),'/view/') !== false) {
    
    $Epsiodes = $node->getAttribute('href')[0];
    
   }
   
  }

Comment: If you need 1 *specific* link with `/vue/` in it, and there are many links with that searchable string, you will need to find an additional identifier so you can single out the link you want. Or, do you mean you only need one of *any* of those links?

Comment: there is 1000 links with /vue/ in it and i just need to get one of them dosent matter what one

Comment: You need to edit your question and add the code you have tried, and to make it more clear you don't care which link you need, any of those..

Comment: edited the question added codes

Comment: Your are looking for `/view/` and not `/vue/` in your code, is it a typo? Which one you want to find?

Comment: hi yeh thats a type its vue my fault sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using XPath (and `DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile` instead of `file_get_contents`) will be more straight forward to do that:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$hrefNodeList = $xp->query('//a/@href[contains(., "/vue/")][1]');

if ($hrefNodeList->length)
    $result = $hrefNodeList->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

XPath query details:

```
//    # anywhere in the DOM tree
a     # "a" tag
/
@href # href attribute
[     # start a condition
  contains(., "/vue/")  # the current element `.` must contain `/vue/`
]     # close the condition
[1]   # only one item (the first)
```

Note that even with only one result `DOMXPath::query` returns always a nodelist (but with only one element)

Comment: Hi this is throwing me loads of errors about the webpage i am loading so i tried putting @before the $dom->loadhtmlfile and its just a blank page i get now

Comment: this dose seem like the best option if can have it fixed so it stops throwing errors

Comment: @mobolog66: first read the errors messages, if errors are due to a bad formatted html document (that is very frequent), put `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` at the start of the script.

Comment: @mobolog66: be sure to pass the url of the page to `DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile()`, not the html content. If you want you can test only with `DOMDocument::loadHTML()` but this time with the html content.

Comment: Hi wen i add that to the code all i get is a blank age :/

Comment: this is all the code in the file and it just gives me a blank page example is a test url for code only

<?php
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$url = 'http://www.example.com'
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$hrefNodeList = $xp->query('//a/@href[contains(., "/vue/")][1]');

if ($hrefNodeList->length)
    $result = $hrefNodeList->item(0)->nodeValue;

?>

Comment: @mobolog66: And without `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` What are the error messages? Are you sure there are "a" tags with an href attribute that contains "/vue/" in the page?

Comment: Hi the errors i get are Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' and then Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Unexpected end tag : div and yes i am 100% sure the eliments are there

Comment: @mobolog66: Ok, these warnings are not important, this is not the problem. What returns `var_dump($hrefNodeList->length)` ? *(put it at the end of the code)*?

Comment: Hi i got it working thanks for all your help it seemed to be a problem in a function i was calling that was no returning the right eliment so was not passing any url to the xpath at all !